# How to save an object using Spring Data ElasticSearchTemplate

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How do I save an entity using Spring Data `ElasticSearchTemplate`? Can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `index()` is the [method for saving an entity in Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java#L378) using the template.

Take a look at [this sample application](https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories/ElasticsearchFacetTests.java#L47) that uses .index() to prepare a JUnit test:

```
public void before() {
        elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Article.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Article.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Article.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Article.class, true);

        IndexQuery article1 = new ArticleBuilder("1").title("article four").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addAuthor(MOHSIN_HUSEN).addAuthor(JONATHAN_YAN).score(10).buildIndex();
        IndexQuery article2 = new ArticleBuilder("2").title("article three").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addAuthor(MOHSIN_HUSEN).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(20).buildIndex();
        IndexQuery article3 = new ArticleBuilder("3").title("article two").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addAuthor(ARTUR_KONCZAK).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2001).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(30).buildIndex();
        IndexQuery article4 = new ArticleBuilder("4").title("article one").addAuthor(RIZWAN_IDREES).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2002).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2001).addPublishedYear(YEAR_2000).score(40).buildIndex();

        elasticsearchTemplate.index(article1);
        elasticsearchTemplate.index(article2);
        elasticsearchTemplate.index(article3);
        elasticsearchTemplate.index(article4);
        elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Article.class, true);
    }
```

You can, also, use [`bulkIndex` for multiple indexes](https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/ComplexNestedTypeContactTests.java#L79) making use of [Elasticsearch's bulk index feature](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: what about for updating and searching?

Comment: For updates I think you have [`update()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java#L388) and for searching a lot other methods from the same template (query, count, queryForPage etc). I suggest having a look at the source code of `ElasticSearchTemplate`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Employee employee = new Employee(1,"Mike");

IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder()
                .withId(employee.getId())
                .withIndexName(indexName).withObject(employee)
                .withType(indexName).build();

elasticsearchTemplate.index(indexQuery);
```